# passing variable by reference

Tags: c++, reference, pass-by-reference

I have this function:

```
void fun(int x, int& sum)
{
sum = x * x;
}
```

what is wrong with:

```
fun(4, &y);
fun(4,5);
```

Comment: have you tried to compile and run this? also what is `y`? the second form won't compile for sure

Comment: The first form won't be compiled too

Comment: Also related: [What are rvalues, lvalues, xvalues, glvalues, and prvalues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3601602/what-are-rvalues-lvalues-xvalues-glvalues-and-prvalues).

Answer (score 0):

`&y` is not a reference. It is a pointer to variable `y`. If you want to pass it by reference you just pass it like so:

```
fun(4, y);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this function call

```
fun(4, &y);
```

argument `y` has type of pointer while the corresponding parameter is  reference to `int`.

If `y` is defined like

```
int y;
```

then the valid function call will look like

```
fun(4, y);
```

This function call is invalid

```
fun(4,5);
```

because the second argument is a temporary expression that is not `lvalue`. Thus it may be bound to a constant reference. However the corresponding parameter is declared as a non-constant reference because the parameter is changed in the function. Thus the compiler will issue a diagnostic message.